# Can't restore my backed-up data

Tags: hard-drive, backup

Currently I am using Ubuntu 14.04.01 LTS. On in minimum monthly basis I have produced a complete Image of my hdd with `dd if=/dev/sda of=~/backup.img`. I tried to update to 16.04, but the system has crashed. I removed everything from my hdd and tried to reinstall the image with `dd if=~/backup.img of=/dev/sda`. After that I see when using `fdisk`- command `p` that there is a `/dev/sda1` partition again with sufficient space in it. I can see all the basic folders but I can not access them and get `inode/x-corrupted`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First I would advise you to use (for the next backup creation) the dd commands presented on this page: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_cloning#Cloning_an_entire_hard_disk (especially the flags conv=noerror,sync) because I used them to sucessfully create ghosts and restore them later on 3 different computers. Question: how do you run dd to restore the image: live usb, another computer with an external disk adaptater,... ?

Comment: I did it from boot SD. At the moment the only interesting thing for me is to restore some folder from image, if possible. Made some trials with loop-cevice w/o success.